# which libc time gives me the time of day?

Tags: c, glibc, raku

Fedora 33
Raku

I want to talk to lic.so.6 with NativeCall for an example I am writing.  I have found

- https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Function-Index.html
- https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getting-the-Time.html#index-clock_005fgettime

But I can't figure out which one will just give me the time of day (21:02:03)

### Scratching my head,

Comment: See also https://modules.raku.org/dist/Time::localtime

Comment: Added tags. I don't think this actually concerns Raku only.

Comment: Are you looking for [the functions dealing with broken-down time](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Broken_002ddown-Time.html)?

Comment: Virtually all C functions return a `tm` struct that includes fields for the full date and time (sometimes the fields are ignored, but they're always technically there).  You will need to format it separately after getting it.  If you are wanting to pass a time into a NativeCall sub, you will probably need to mirror the `tm` struct in a Raku class with the `is repr('CStruct')` trait applied.

Comment: Virtually all C **time** functions, I mean

Comment: @Todd Afaict your Q doesn't have anything to do with C, or libc, or its functions, or Raku, or NativeCall, beyond reading/understanding/following their doc. Their doc is the sort you get when it's written in volunteers' spare time, but it's what everyone else is using, so you must be patient with it. The expectation on SO is that you only post questions *after* first doing your best to read/follow/understand that doc, *and* googling for examples (in this case, in C, not Raku), *and* trying hard to get corresponding code to work. Would you say you *have* already tried as hard as you could?

Comment: @Raiph  I had Raku and NativeCall on the mind as it was my eventual goal.   So, point taken on Raku and NativeCall But this post was not that goal.  It was to understand glibc's time  function.  As such, I should have tagged with glibc.  And I do not know how more apropos glibc.so.6 is to glibc, so I do not understand you other point.  Did you think I was asking how to write the NativeCall?  I was not.  I will get around to that on my own.  If I get in trouble, I will post a new.

Comment: @Raiph Oh yo know what, there is no "g" in "libc" as in /usr/lib64/libc.so.6.   My bad

Comment: @Todd Do you agree you do not follow the guidelines on the [Ask a Question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) page? "Include *details* about your *goal*. Describe expected *and actual* results. Include any error messages". You didn't do that. "*Show what you’ve tried* ..." You skipped that. "share the minimum amount of code others need to reproduce your problem" Instead you wrote "scratching my head". Do you understand I am breaking SO norms by even trying to answer your Q instead of leaving it unanswered and just voting to close it? Would you *prefer* I voted to close?

Answer (score 7):

In principle I shouldn't be trying to write an answer.<sup>**[1]**</sup> But some say impatience and/or hubris can be a virtue...

> just give me the time of day (21:02:03)

The page you linked only lists functions that the introductory doc says have "no relation to the way people normally think of ... time".<sup>**[3]**</sup>

---

I looked at the module Håkon linked, and a module it uses: [P5localtime](https://modules.raku.org/dist/P5localtime:cpan:ELIZABETH/lib/P5localtime.pm6). It includes this line:

```
my sub get-ctime(int64 is rw --> Str) is native is symbol<ctime> {*}
```

This calls the C function `ctime` that's documented on the [**Formatting Calendar Time**](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Formatting-Calendar-Time.html) page of the site you linked.

My guess is that you want to call the `ctime_r` function or similar.

---

I recall recently reading an exchange between yourself and someone knowledgeable about such things (ugexe?) about how you can specifically pick up `glibc.so.6` rather than some other version, so I'll skip that wrinkle.

## Footnotes

<sup>**[1]**</sup> I'm happy to give you the time of day, though it might not be the time of day you want. I know next to nothing about the relevant ingredients<sup>**[2]**</sup>. My only excuse for answering your question is that I sometimes have sufficient time and the sort of hubris and impatience to answer questions about topics I know nothing about that are *not* the virtues Larry meant.

<sup>**[2]**</sup> I don't recall using C to get any production code written. I don't know the libc time functions. I've only used NativeCall to do a few trivial things like some 'hello world' tests I recall doing when I read [this blog post](https://justrakudoit.wordpress.com/2011/01/28/zavolaj/).

<sup>**[3]**</sup> The page you're looking at -- [**Getting the time**](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getting-the-Time.html) -- presumably sounds promising to you, but if you go up a few levels in the web site you'll come to a page titled [**Time Basics**](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Time-Basics.html) that strongly suggests to me that you want to use functions from either the [**Formatting Calendar Time**](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Formatting-Calendar-Time.html) page or the [**Broken-down Time**](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Broken_002ddown-Time.html) page.<sup>**[4]**</sup>

<sup>**[4]**</sup> Though I do have doubts. First, I don't know what I'm talking about.<sup>**[2]**</sup> Second, each of the functions has annotations like this that are troubling:

> AS-Unsafe heap lock

I'll leave it up to you to read the [POSIX Safety Concepts](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/POSIX-Safety-Concepts.html) doc that explains those terms, so you can adapt accordingly.

Comment: I picked time from glibc on purpose to make up and example of how to use Object Orientated class to represent the structure.   As far as wanting the time, raku has time functions OUT THE NOSE.  The goal is the example.  I did state that in my original question

Comment: I specifically need to with function it is in time.h (libc.so.6). I need to know the hard way.   I think it is /usr/include/bits/types/time_t.h
/* Return the current time and put it in *TIMER if TIMER is not NULL.  */
extern time_t time (time_t *__timer) __THROW;

Comment: "I specifically need to with function it is in time.h (libc.so.6). I need to know the hard way." Then why didn't you *say* so, in your Q, from the start, rather than wait until I've wasted time answering you, to mention this critically important detail in a comment on my answer? How was I supposed to know that you understood that there were other more appropriate functions (also in `time.h`), and they would be fine examples of using Raku and NativeCall, but you were deliberately choosing to ignore those simpler functions, in favour of a harder way of doing things, when you had not said so?

Answer (score 1):

To get libc.so.6 to cough up the local time, you first have to get the raw system time from `time` and then feed `localtime` the raw system time to gets your hours, minutes, etc..

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env raku
use NativeCall;


class tm is repr('CStruct') { 
   has int32   $.tm_sec;              # Seconds.    [0-60] (1 leap second)
   has int32   $.tm_min;            # Minutes.  [0-59] 
   has int32   $.tm_hour;       # Hours.    [0-23]
   has int32   $.tm_mday;       # Day.      [1-31]
   has int32   $.tm_mon;            # Month.    [0-11]
   has int32   $.tm_year;       # Year  - 1900.   Add 1900 to this to get a four digit year
   has int32   $.tm_wday;       # Day of week.  [0-6]
   has int32   $.tm_yday;         # Days in year.[0-365]
   has int32   $.tm_isdst;    # DST.        [-1/0/1]
   has int64   $.tm_gmtoff;     # Seconds east of UTC.
   has byte    $.tm_zone;    # Timezone abbreviation.
   
   # note: the mysterious "time_t" structure is a "long, long int" or int64
  
     
   # /usr/lib64/libc.so.6    `'c',v6` converts to "libc.so.6"
   # C: time (&rawtime);     /* "&rawtime" is the address of "rawtime" */
   sub  time( int64 is rw ) is native( 'c', v6 ) { * };    # "is rw" makes it a pointer
   
   # C: timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);   /* "&rawtime" is the address of "rawtime" */
   sub  localtime( int64 is rw ) returns tm is native( 'c', v6 ) { * };  # "is rw" makes it a pointer
   

   method GetRawTime( --> int64 ) {
      my int64 $rawtime;
      time( $rawtime );
      return $rawtime;
   }
          
   method GetLocalTime() returns tm  {
      # my Str $SubName = &?ROUTINE.name;
      my $time = tm.new;
      my int64 $rawtime = 0;
      
      $rawtime = tm.GetRawTime();      
      $time = localtime( $rawtime );
      return $time;
   }    
   
}

my int64 $RawTime = 0;
$RawTime = tm.GetRawTime();
print "raw time = <" ~ $RawTime ~ ">\n";

my $SysTime = tm.new;
$SysTime    = tm.GetLocalTime();
print "Local Time HH:MM:SS <" ~ $SysTime.tm_hour ~ ":" ~ 
      $SysTime.tm_min ~ ":" ~ $SysTime.tm_sec ~ ">\n";
print "year = <" ~ $SysTime.tm_year + 1900 ~ ">\n";
```

A sample output:

```
$ LinSysTime.pl6
raw time = <1608970172>
Local Time HH:MM:SS <0:9:32>
year = <2020>
```