# What is the structure of libc.so.6 time.c

Tags: libc, time.h

Okay, I give up.  I can't read C for my life!

1. What is the structure of time_t below?

   /usr/include/bits/types/time_t.h

   ```
   #ifndef __time_t_defined
   #define __time_t_defined 1

   #include <bits/types.h>

   /* Returned by `time'.  */
   typedef __time_t time_t;

   #endif
   ```

"time_t" is used here:

```
   /usr/include/bits/types/time_t.h

   /* Return the current time and put it in *TIMER if TIMER is not NULL.  */
   extern time_t time (time_t *__timer) __THROW;
```

"__THROW" is throw an exception.

2. is the first "time_t" the returned value?  What is
   its "structure"?  Is it the mystical time_t.h that I
   can't figure out?
3. what is the "time"?  Is that the name of the function?
   Is the first "time_t" defining the structure of the
   returned value of "time"?
4. what is the second "time_t"?  Why two of them?
5. I presume "*___timer " is a pointers, but to what
   structure?
6. is tm.h used anywhere in the above?

   ```
    /usr/include/bits/types/struct_tm.h

   struct tm
   {
     int tm_sec;        /* Seconds.    [0-60] (1 leap second) */
     int tm_min;        /* Minutes.    [0-59] */
     int tm_hour;        /* Hours.    [0-23] */
     int tm_mday;        /* Day.        [1-31] */
     int tm_mon;        /* Month.    [0-11] */
     int tm_year;        /* Year    - 1900.  */
     int tm_wday;        /* Day of week.    [0-6] */
     int tm_yday;        /* Days in year.[0-365]    */
     int tm_isdst;        /* DST.        [-1/0/1]*/

   # ifdef    __USE_MISC
     long int tm_gmtoff;    /* Seconds east of UTC.  */
     const char *tm_zone;    /* Timezone       abbreviation.  */
   # else
     long int __tm_gmtoff;    /* Seconds east of UTC.  */
     const char *__tm_zone;    /* Timezone abbreviation.  */
   # endif
   };
   ```

   #endif

### Yours in confusion,

Comment: You need to be really precise with the header names and identifiers. `time_t` and `__time_t` are distinct identifiers. You mention `tm.h`, but then quote a completely different header file.

Comment: Hi @Florian, `typedef __time_t time_t;` means that time_t is of type __time_t.   I was directly quoting `/usr/include/bits/types/time_t.h`.  Does yours differ?

Answer (score 1):

time_t is a long long int for a 64 bit integer.

Edit: to answer @lbragile comment:

Here is a trick the C guys gave me when you can't figure out something from the .h headers"

```
   #include <time.h>

   void func(char*);

   int main(void) {
       time_t x;
       func(x);
   }
```

I then try to compile with gcc like this:

```
  gcc -c test.c
```

This produces these warning messages:

```
  C:\c>gcc -c test.c
  test.c: In function 'main':
  test.c:8:10: warning: passing argument 1 of 'func' makes pointer from
   integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     func(x);
          ^
  test.c:3:11: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'time_t'
   {aka 'long long int'}
   void func(char*);
           ^~~~~
```

Basically the error message will tell you what it is.  time_t is a 64 bit integer: {aka 'long long int'}

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27933482)

Comment: @lbragile, yes it does.  The question was "What is the structure of time_t below?".  The answer is it is a {aka 'long long int'} or long, long integer, or 64 bit integer, or int64.  And it perfectly answered my question for me.  Go see my use of it over on  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65421378/which-libc-time-gives-me-the-time-of-day/65428914?noredirect=1#comment115709698_65428914